# Requirejs static included script the callback does not get executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, requirejs

In a current project i need to use RequireJS as well with dynamic included modules as with static included javascripts.

The static included scripts are needed for every page and get concatinated at the end of the development process. These are for example jQuery jQueryUi and some more scripts like an autosuggest script.

The dynamic part is only used on some pages like a configurator which has an additional script needed that is to big to be loaded on every page. That's why this script is loaded as a module on the page where it is needed.

While jQuery and jQueryUi are playing nice and are available as amd modules due to the how the factory method gets executed:

```
(function(t){
    "function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define('jquery-ui',["jquery"],t):t(jQuery)
})(function(t){...});
```

This is not true for the autosuggest part. Though i added the functionality in exact the same pattern:

```
(function(t){
    "function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define('suggest',['jquery','jquery-ui'],t):t(jQuery)
})(function(t){
    console.log('yeah');
});
```

The yeah part inside the factory does not get executed.

What am i missing? Is there anything else needed to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

From the RequireJS documentation (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html):

> Ideally the scripts you load will be modules that are defined by
>   calling define(). However, you may need to use some traditional/legacy
>   "browser globals" scripts that do not express their dependencies via
>   define(). For those, you can use the shim config. To properly express
>   their dependencies.

You can try using something like:

```
requirejs.config({
    ...
    shim: {
        'suggest': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui'],
            exports: 'suggest'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You might need to add `sugget` to you `paths` property too.

Comment: I should emphasize that the autosuggest file also has a full define block with dependancies.

So its not a plain js file but an amd compatible structured file which gets included via script tag.

If im not completly wrong the shim is only needed for plain js files. In this case i suppose that i dont need to add this to the config.

Comment: Can you show the `autosuggest` file? If I could take a look at the module definition, I would probably be able to help better.

Comment: Create a gist with the suggest file. If you need more detailes please let me know. https://gist.github.com/garbast/9af7782e71507fda37d6bb637de5ca9c